# Download size of a video on YouTube vs through third party applications

Tags: youtube, video-download

Why the size of a video downloaded from YouTube on YouTube app is smaller (≈30mb) than the same video downloaded from other YouTube video downloader apps, copying the link of YouTube video (≈80mb)

On YouTube, the video is in parts as it is recieved from the servers in some wierd format. Are they kinda more compressed? Or something tricky?

Comment: what are your download settings: https://www.youtube.com/account_downloads

Comment: To your second Q about format, YouTube tries to obfuscate their stream so that it is hard to pirate it.  3rd party apps work around this by collecting all the file fragments and recombining them to a single file and in a file  format that video apps recognize.

Comment: @BlindSpots It was at 360p and 20 min of video. Same for both instances.      So do you mean that the download size increases because of that recombining?